# Scikit-image GLIBCXX ImportError. Is the problem with skimage, Anaconda, or Ubuntu?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, glibc, scikit-image

I am running a fairly cutting-edge Miniconda setup on Ubuntu 22.04.  Getting Tensorflow GPU installed without pain is what sold me on Anaconda, but I'm not sure that it handles every situation well.  I thought it was supposed to handle non-Python dependencies well.

My Miniconda version is 4.13.0.  I am using mamba as the default solver.  The virtual environment in which I'm attempting to use scikit-image 0.19.2 has access to conda-forge, and is running Python 3.10.4.

Many parts of scikit-image import just fine, and are working for me.  The flood fill function is not.  Here is minimal code which provokes the error.  Just the import statement!

```
from skimage.segmentation import flood_fill
```

Here is the traceback.

```
  File "/home/john/src/Python/misc/flood fill backend error minimal example.py", line 10, in <module>
    from skimage.segmentation import flood_fill

  File "/home/john/miniconda3/envs/png16/lib/python3.10/site-packages/skimage/segmentation/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .active_contour_model import active_contour

  File "/home/john/miniconda3/envs/png16/lib/python3.10/site-packages/skimage/segmentation/active_contour_model.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ..filters import sobel

  File "/home/john/miniconda3/envs/png16/lib/python3.10/site-packages/skimage/_shared/lazy.py", line 64, in __getattr__
    submod = importlib.import_module(

  File "/home/john/miniconda3/envs/png16/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

  File "/home/john/miniconda3/envs/png16/lib/python3.10/site-packages/skimage/filters/edges.py", line 17, in <module>
    from ..restoration.uft import laplacian

  File "/home/john/miniconda3/envs/png16/lib/python3.10/site-packages/skimage/restoration/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .deconvolution import wiener, unsupervised_wiener, richardson_lucy

  File "/home/john/miniconda3/envs/png16/lib/python3.10/site-packages/skimage/restoration/deconvolution.py", line 5, in <module>
    from scipy.signal import convolve

  File "/home/john/miniconda3/envs/png16/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/signal/__init__.py", line 309, in <module>
    from . import _sigtools, windows

  File "/home/john/miniconda3/envs/png16/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/signal/windows/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from ._windows import *

  File "/home/john/miniconda3/envs/png16/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/signal/windows/_windows.py", line 7, in <module>
    from scipy import linalg, special, fft as sp_fft

  File "/home/john/miniconda3/envs/png16/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/fft/__init__.py", line 91, in <module>
    from ._helper import next_fast_len

  File "/home/john/miniconda3/envs/png16/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/fft/_helper.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ._pocketfft import helper as _helper

  File "/home/john/miniconda3/envs/png16/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/fft/_pocketfft/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .basic import *

  File "/home/john/miniconda3/envs/png16/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/fft/_pocketfft/basic.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import pypocketfft as pfft

ImportError: /home/john/miniconda3/envs/png16/lib/python3.10/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/../../../../.././libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found (required by /home/john/miniconda3/envs/png16/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/fft/_pocketfft/pypocketfft.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
```

I have read several posts concerning GLIBCXX errors.  I cannot tell whether any of these apply to my situation.  However, one of the posts showed how to check which GLIBCXX versions are available to my OS.  Here is the output of `strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX`:

```
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_3.4.21
GLIBCXX_3.4.22
GLIBCXX_3.4.23
GLIBCXX_3.4.24
GLIBCXX_3.4.25
GLIBCXX_3.4.26
GLIBCXX_3.4.27
GLIBCXX_3.4.28
GLIBCXX_3.4.29
GLIBCXX_3.4.30
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

This suggests that my OS has a copy of GLIBCXX_3.4.30.  But my Anaconda virtual environment is unable to find it.

As my title states, I don't know where the fault lies.  With scikit-image?  With Anaconda?  With Ubuntu?

Any advice is appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

My Anaconda virtual environment was the problem.

When I was setting up my venv for use with scikit-learn, the solver told me that certain dependencies were not available on the **conda-forge** channel.  Therefore I added the **defaults** channel and proceeded.  This caused scikit-image to break, as some of its dependencies came from **conda-forge** and others came from **defaults**.

I started a fresh virtual environment and tried again.  This time, even though I only enabled the **conda-forge** channel, all dependencies were installed, and the ImportError disappeared.  Perhaps **conda-forge** was temporarily broken the last time I tried it?  I am not sure.

In any event, the problem is solved.